# A tool to convert MATLAB code to Python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I have a bunch of MATLAB code from my MS thesis which I now want to convert to Python (using numpy/scipy and matplotlib) and distribute as open-source. I know the similarity between MATLAB and Python scientific libraries, and converting them manually will be not more than a fortnight (provided that I work towards it every day for some time). I was wondering if there was already any tool available which can do the conversion.

Comment: another possibility is to release your source code as is, and test it in Octave (www.gnu.org/software/octave) which has 99% matlab competability.

Comment: @josliber: Can we move this question to http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com so that it can be reopened?

Comment: @andersongreen the question is too old for migration

Comment: I think now the best way to do this is to use matlab built-in tool [mcc](https://www.mathworks.com/help/mps/ml_code/mcc.html)

Answer (score 186, accepted):

There are several tools for converting Matlab to Python code.

The only one that's seen recent activity (last commit from June 2018) is [**S**mall **M**atlab t**o** **P**ython compiler](https://github.com/victorlei/smop) (also developed here: [SMOP@chiselapp](http://chiselapp.com/user/victorlei/repository/smop-dev/home)).

Other options include:

- [LiberMate](https://github.com/awesomebytes/libermate): translate from Matlab to Python and SciPy (Requires Python 2, last update 4 years ago).
- [OMPC](http://ompc.juricap.com/): Matlab to Python (a bit outdated).
- [Mat2py](https://github.com/miaoever/Mat2py): Matlab to Python (Requires Python 2).

Also, for those interested in an interface between the two languages and *not* conversion:

- [`pymatlab`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pymatlab): communicate from Python by sending data to the MATLAB workspace, operating on them with scripts and pulling back the resulting data.
- [Python-Matlab wormholes](https://code.google.com/p/python-matlab-wormholes/): both directions of interaction supported.
- [Python-Matlab bridge](https://github.com/arokem/python-matlab-bridge): use Matlab from within Python, offers matlab_magic for iPython, to execute normal matlab code from within ipython.
- [PyMat](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pymat/): Control Matlab session from Python.
- [`pymat2`](http://code.google.com/p/pymat2/): continuation of the seemingly abandoned PyMat.
- [`mlabwrap`](http://mlabwrap.sourceforge.net/), [mlabwrap-purepy](https://github.com/cpbotha/mlabwrap-purepy): make Matlab look like Python library (based on PyMat).
- [`oct2py`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/oct2py) ([repository](https://github.com/blink1073/oct2py)): run GNU Octave commands from within Python.
- [`pymex`](http://vader.cse.lehigh.edu/%7Eperkins/pymex.html): Embeds the Python Interpreter in Matlab, also on [File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27255).
- [`matpy`](https://bitbucket.org/glglgl/matpy): Access MATLAB in various ways: create variables, access .mat files, direct interface to MATLAB engine (requires MATLAB be installed).
- [MatPy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/matpy/): Python package for numerical linear algebra and plotting with a MatLab-like interface.

Btw might be helpful to look here for other migration tips:

- http://bci2000.org/downloads/BCPy2000/Migration.html

On a different note, for people who might find it useful there is:

- [`matlab2fortran`](https://github.com/elmanuelito/matlab2fortran)

Comment: Does anyone have a comment on which of these works best or which cases fail?

Comment: I haven't tested them yet either, but it seems like smop has the sole distinction of being actively maintained, by the original developer, on github, with a test suite.

Comment: which one is the fastest to call matlab functions out of the methods establishing an interface?

Answer (score 8):

There's also oct2py which can call .m files within python

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/oct2py

It requires GNU Octave, which is highly compatible with MATLAB.

https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/

Comment: Although this may look like a link-only NAA, it is actually an appropriate answer to the question. That the question is inappropriate (off-topic) is a separate issue.