# conversion of matlab to python code

Tags: python, matlab

I am working on matlab conversion code to python.
I do not understand these 2 lines of code.

```
d1 = s(1:3,2) - s(1:3,1);
d2 = s(1:3,end) - s(1:3,end-1);
```

what these 2 lines are doing? can anyone explain me?
and how will i convert this in python?

Comment: Have tried printing the results by parts in MATLAB? What did you get?

Comment: i do not have matlab but I need to do conversion

Comment: Try [this](http://www.compileonline.com/execute_matlab_online.php) to run MATLAB code online.

Comment: thanks. can you tell me any documentation which will direct me towards easy conversion of matlab code to python code?

Comment: Try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17535694/2670792) in another SO post.

Comment: Also have a look at this: http://wiki.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users

Answer (score 3):

**In Matlab:**

```
% Matlab
s = [1,2,3,4,5; ...
    6,7,8,9,10; ...
    11,12,13,14,15];
d1 = s(1:3,2) - s(1:3,1);
d2 = s(1:3,end) - s(1:3,end-1);

disp('--s--')
disp(s)
disp('--d1--')
disp(d1)
disp('--d2--')
disp(d2)

disp('--s(1:3,2)--')
disp(s(1:3,2))
disp('--s(1:3,1)--')
disp(s(1:3,1))

disp('--s(1:3,end)--')
disp(s(1:3,end))
disp('--s(1:3,end-1)--')
disp(s(1:3,end-1))
```

**can be translated to Python as:**

```
# Python
import numpy as np

s = np.asarray([ \
    1,2,3,4,5, \
    6,7,8,9,10, \
    11,12,13,14,15]).reshape(3,-1);
d1 = s[0:3,1] - s[0:3,0];
d2 = s[0:3,-1] - s[:3,-2];

print '--s--'
print s
print '--d1--'
print d1
print '--d2--'
print d2

print '--s[0:3,1]--'
print s[0:3,1]
print '--s[0:3,0]--'
print s[0:3,0]

print '--s[0:3,-1]--'
print s[0:3,-1]
print '--s[0:3,-2]--'
print s[0:3,-2]
```

**Results of Matlab:**

```
--s--
    1    2    3    4    5
    6    7    8    9   10
   11   12   13   14   15
--d1--
   1
   1
   1
--d2--
   1
   1
   1
--s(1:3,2)--
    2
    7
   12
--s(1:3,1)--
    1
    6
   11
--s(1:3,end)--
    5
   10
   15
--s(1:3,end-1)--
    4
    9
   14
```

**vs of Python:**

```
--s--
[[ 1  2  3  4  5]
 [ 6  7  8  9 10]
 [11 12 13 14 15]]
--d1--
[1 1 1]
--d2--
[1 1 1]
--s[0:3,1]--
[ 2  7 12]
--s[0:3,0]--
[ 1  6 11]
--s[0:3,-1]--
[ 5 10 15]
--s[0:3,-2]--
[ 4  9 14]
```

They match.

Evaluate Matlab code online [/here/](http://www.compileonline.com/execute_matlab_online.php) and Python code [/here/](http://www.compileonline.com/execute_python_online.php), [/here/](http://repl.it/languages/Python) and with packages [/here/](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/try-ipython/).

Comment: I'd probably prefer `np.array([[1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9,10], [11,12,13,14,15]])` there - note that you don't need `\ ` to continue a line within `{[(`

Comment: @Eric Your point is totally correct. We just tried to keep `Python` translation similar to `Matlab` code as much as possible.

Comment: Also, you really shouldn't use semicolons in python

Answer (score 2):

s is a matrix. 
s(1:3,2) creates a vector from rows 1 to 3 and column 2. 
s(1:3,1) creates a vector from rows 1 to 3 and column 1. 
d1 is then another vector being the element by element difference

end is special syntax for the last row or column. end-1 is the penultimate row/column

Answer (score 1):

`d1`: the difference between 2nd column and 1st column of the first 3 rows of `s`

`d2`: the difference between last column and the one before last column of the first 3 rows of `s`

You can test it [online](http://www.compileonline.com/execute_matlab_online.php)