# Matlab fscanf, fseek, and fread in Python

Tags: python, matlab, scanf

I have a Matlab code that I am trying to convert into Python. I have a binary output from a Fortran program which is read into Matlab using fread, fscanf and fseek. I would like to convert this into python, however I have not had any luck. Here is a sample from the Matlab script;

```
[fid,message]=fopen(fname,'r');
junk=' ';

while junk(1)~='P'
    junk=fscanf(fid,'%s',1);
end

fseek(fid,-length(junk),0);

while ((sign~='+')&(sign~='-'))
    sign=char(fread(fid,1));
end

fread(fid,2,'float');
fc=fread(fid,1,'float');
fread(fid,2,'float');
sd=fread(fid,1,'float');
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17535694/541038

Comment: Almost managed to complete the script :(. Good spot :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [A tool to convert MATLAB code to Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845292/a-tool-to-convert-matlab-code-to-python)

Comment: Python's [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) module is great for reading binary files.

Comment: What are the data you're trying to read and in what format you want them?