# How to convert a MATLAB code into a Python format

Tags: python-3.x

I have a difficult MATLAB code which needs to be converted by tomorrow. These many years I have been working with Python. Since MATLAB is a new Platform for me, I wanted to know if there is any online tool which can convert MATLAB code into Python directly.

Comment: https://github.com/victorlei/smop

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A tool to convert MATLAB code to Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845292/a-tool-to-convert-matlab-code-to-python)