# python equivalent of matlab code to generate data file

Tags: python, matlab, syntax

**Matlab code**

```
for i=1:N
        fprintf(fid,'%g 1 0 %g %g %g\n',i,coords(i,:));
    end
    fclose(fid);
end
```

**Python code** (converted by me)

```
for i in range ( 0 , N  ):
    fdata.write("%g 1 0 %g %g %g\n" % (coords(i,:)))
```

I got the following error.

```
File "<ipython-input-8-c5647c2ae12d>", line 44
    fdata.write("%g 1 0 %g %g %g\n" % (coords(i,:)))
                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a format string. You cannot write to file in python 3.x using that syntax. The syntax for writing to file is:

```
with open("file.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(f"{variable}") # this is called a format string where the variable can be any datatype
```

If your intention is not to write to file then use print(f"{variable}") to print to your terminal under your for-loop.

These links might help you: [Matlab to Python code link](https://sweetcode.io/how-to-convert-matlab-code-to-python/), [tool to covert Matlab code to Python code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845292/a-tool-to-convert-matlab-code-to-python) and
[Learn format string](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp#:%7E:text=%20Python%20String%20format%20%28%29%20Method%20%201,using%20named%20indexes%20%7Bprice%7D%2C%20numbered%20indexes...%20More%20).