# "data type not understood" when converting Matlab code to Python

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy

I am trying to convert the following code from  Trefethen's  Spectral Methods in MATLAB to Python.

```
% p6.m - variable coefficient wave equation

% Grid, variable coefficient, and initial data:
  N = 128; h = 2*pi/N; x = h*(1:N); t = 0; dt = h/4;
  c = .2 + sin(x-1).^2;
  v = exp(-100*(x-1).^2); vold = exp(-100*(x-.2*dt-1).^2);

% Time-stepping by leap frog formula:
  tmax = 8; tplot = .15; clf, drawnow, set(gcf,'renderer','zbuffer')
  plotgap = round(tplot/dt); dt = tplot/plotgap;
  nplots = round(tmax/tplot);
  data = [v; zeros(nplots,N)]; tdata = t;
  for i = 1:nplots
    for n = 1:plotgap
      t = t+dt;
      v_hat = fft(v);
      w_hat = 1i*[0:N/2-1 0 -N/2+1:-1] .* v_hat;
      w = real(ifft(w_hat)); 
      vnew = vold - 2*dt*c.*w; vold = v; v = vnew;
    end
    data(i+1,:) = v; tdata = [tdata; t];
  end
  waterfall(x,tdata,data), view(10,70), colormap(1e-6*[1 1 1]);
  axis([0 2*pi 0 tmax 0 5]), ylabel t, zlabel u, grid off
```

For the most part it is going smoothly except for this line of code

```
 data = [v; zeros(nplots,N)]
```

After reading how to convert between Numpy and Matlab here [Link](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html#head-e9a492daa18afcd86e84e07cd2824a9b1b651935) I tried to convert it by doing the following

```
data = np.array(v,zeros(nplots,N))
```

but I get this error

```
 data = np.array(v,zeros(nplots,N));
 TypeError: data type not understood
```

Which I assume is because a numpy array has this structure

```
  numpy.array(object,dtype=none)
```

I would appreciate any help with converting that line. Thank you in advance!

Comment: maybe `np.vstack((v, zeros(nplots, N)))`

Comment: @JBernardo thanks for the reply. i tried the vstack, but I still get the `TypeError: data type not understood` error

Comment: Check the number of parens... There must be to more than the *usual* :)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845292/converting-matlab-to-python?rq=1, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326786/matlab-to-python-code-conversion-numpy-scipy-matplotlib?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data = [v; zeros(nplots,N)]` this is concatenating two matrices and stacken them up, note the `;` in numpy you can use `numpy.concatenate((v, zeros((nplots,N))), axis = 0)` where axis is by which axis you want to concatenate by ...

```
data = np.array(v,zeros(nplots,N));
TypeError: data type not understood
```

basically when you call `np.array` the fist argument must be iterable object, list, tuple and on the **second** argument must be the type ie 'int', 'float32', 'float32' and so on ... but you set the type to `zeros(nplots,N)` `numpy` is complaining that it isn't a type ...
`numpy.zeros` is the same the first argument must be a tuple and the second the type, sorry about that I didn't properly include `()`

it should be `data = numpy.concatenate((v, numpy.zeros((nplots,N))), axis = 0)`  assuming that you want to use `double` type which is the standard type.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried concatenating, but I am still getting the error